# Cauchy sequences on $L^p$ and $L^q$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

Let $\{u_m\}_m$ be a Cauchy sequence on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Let suppose $u_m\longrightarrow u$ on $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

How do I prove that $u_m\longrightarrow u$ on $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Hint: if $u_m \rightarrow u$ in $L^k$, there exists a subsequence $u_{m_j}$ such that $u_{m_j}\rightarrow u$ point wise almost everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe $L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is a Banach space, i.e. it's complete.

Edit: Okay. Since $\{u_m\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^q\cap L^p$, which is complete, then there exists $w \in L^q\cap L^p$ such that $\|u_m-w\|_{L^q\cap L^p} \rightarrow 0$ as $m \rightarrow \infty$. Next, since $u_m\rightarrow u$ in $L^p$ then we have
\begin{align}
\|w-u\|_{L^p} \leq \|w-u_m\|_{L^p\cap L^q}+\|u_m-u\|_{L^p} \rightarrow 0
\end{align}
which means $w=u \in L^p$. In particular, we have that
\begin{align}
\|u_m-u\|_{L^q} \leq \|u_m-u\|_{L^p\cap L^q} = \|u_m-w\|_{L^q\cap L^p}\rightarrow 0.
\end{align}

Comment: How to prove this observation? That is, I know how to prove it, but is it easier than the question itself?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz I have added to the post. However, I don't understand what you mean by "is it easier than the question itself". Could you elaborate on your question?

Comment: I imagine that the proof of completeness of $L^p \cap L^q$ follows the same steps as the proof of completeness of $L^p$, i.e. one constructs a subsequence convergent a.e. Or maybe there is some simpler proof? The way I see it, proving the observation requires answering the question along the way.